# Migrate Apache Archiva to Nexus Milestone 6 or 7

Tags: maven, nexus, archiva

i am trying to migrate my maven artifacts form apache archiva repository manager to Nexus OSS Milestone 7 
https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/215781148-Nexus-Repository-Manager-3-0-Technology-Preview-Milestone-7-Release-
the only migration guide available on nexus documentaion site is about earlier versions (Nexus 2.X).
any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation about Nexus 3.0 is [here](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/index.html) no ?

Comment: Yes sure, But they don't talk about migrating archiva repositories. unless it is a 2.x version.

Comment: Yeah you're right i found only Nexus 2.12 if i got an answer i'll tag you

Comment: Thanks a lot. i'll be grateful.